# OpenSSL Extract encryptedKeyPackage from x509 certificate

Tags: c, openssl, x509, asn.1, der

I'm very new to OpenSSL (been using it for literally two days). I'm using OpenSSL version 1.0.1, and I'm trying to implement OpenSSL functions to extract a particular x509 OID from an ASN.1 (DER-encoded) signedData Package (in particular, the OID is 2.16.840.1.101.2.1.2.78.2, id-ct-KP-encryptedKeyPkg). Just for now, I'm only trying to have a program that can extract this data from the package given any ASN.1 encoded package. I'm able to encode the certificate into a buffer using the following code:

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>

int main()
{
    /* for brevity, please assume "encrypted" points to a DER-encoded buffer */
    char* encrypted = malloc( 3000 ); 
    int sizeOfEncrypted = 3000;       // assume this number is correct

    BIO* bp = BIO_new( BIO_s_mem() );
    ASN1_parse( bp, (unsigned char*) encrypted, (long) encryptedSize, 4 );

    BUF_MEM *bptr;
    BIO_get_mem_ptr( bp, &bptr );
    BIO_set_close( bp, BIO_NOCLOSE );
    BIO_free( bp );

    return 0;
}
```

If I write the bytes of the buffer pointed to by "bptr" to a file, I get all the fields of the encoded data, similar to the output of:

```
 $ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in my_pkg.dat -i
```

I've confirmed the data is correct, but now as I mentioned, I'm looking for the correct OpenSSL instructions to extract a particular OID (so instead of X509_get_version(), it would be something like X509_get_encryptedKeyPkg(), per se, for a particular OID). How can I do this? I can write code that just searches for the OID in the cert and can potentially parse the data I need, but I'm almost certain/hoping OpenSSL has the tools to do that already, and more reliably. Once again, I'm an OpenSSL noobie, so I'm looking as best as I can for the solution on the internet, but perhaps I'm not using the right wording. Please let me know if you can help me out. Thanks!